# creating FTP login in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, ftp

How to create a FTP login for new user in ubuntu 16.04 , I tried all documentation but no use, please suggest easy way to do this

Comment: Which FTP server are you using? Mostly they authenticate users against PAM, so adding a user on the computer should be enough.

Comment: I am using hsftpd , I need to give only ftp access to that particular user..

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that you're using hsftpd, but I assume that there was a typo and it is vsftpd instead, as I can't find any software by the name hsftpd.

There are numerous guides on the internet for configuring vsftpd like you want, here are a few:

- https://websiteforstudents.com/install-vsftpd-ssltls-ubuntu-17-04-17-10/
- http://www.instructables.com/id/VSFTPD-Installation-Setup-on-Ubuntu/
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04 (you can skip step 2, most likely)
- https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-and-configure-vsftpd/